# Find the next textarea using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

HTML

```
<tr id="rowId"><td><textarea class="inputTextarea"></textarea></td><td><textarea class="inputTextarea"></textarea></td></tr>
<tr id="rowId2"><td><textarea class="inputTextarea"></textarea></td><td><textarea class="inputTextarea"></textarea></td></tr>
<tr id="rowId3"><td><textarea class="inputTextarea"></textarea></td><td><textarea class="inputTextarea"></textarea></td></tr>
```

Provided I know rowId, how do I find the next textarea ON THIS PAGE, starting at any arbitary point. I don't mean ANY input, textarea only. I need to be able to start AT ANY row, and progress on to the next textarea, essentially going down the rows.

EDIT
Based on answers, I used the following code to traverse the textareas row by row:

```
var curElt = $('#' + startAt);  //startAt is the first row id   

        for(var i=1; i < 10; i++) {

            $(curElt).find('textarea').eq(0).val(i);
            $(curElt).find('textarea').eq(1).val(i+1);

            curElt = $(curElt).next();
        }
```

Comment: Based on the variety of answers, it appears that your question is clearly not clear enough. Do you just mean that you want to the equivalent of pressing the Tab key, focusing the next text area by source code order/tabIndex? What does the row id have to do with this?

Comment: I have a bunch of rows, each has a unique ID. A user may start pasting data at any given textarea (there are 2 textarea elements per row). The data will be CSV data from Excel. My job is to populate the textareas starting the one user pasted into (hence I know the row ID they are starting from) and on. I am not sure how to explain myself better. I guess TAB comparison works.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) and [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) methods:

```
$('#' + current_row_id).next().find('textarea').eq(0);
```

`next` will get the next sibling, and then `find` will find all of the elements within the set that match the passed-in selector(s), then `eq(0)` will grab the first element in the resulting set returned from `find`.

Comment: if i am at the second textarea, will running this give me the first textarea of rowId3?

Comment: The next() method is for siblings. If you select a table row, then you won't find textarea elements among the siblings or the row.

Answer (score 6):

```
$('#rowId2').find('textarea');
```

That will find both children of the row. If you want the first one, either:

```
$('#rowId2').find('textarea').eq(0); //jQuery object
$('#rowId2').find('textarea')[0];    //DOM Element
```

**Edit**: If you only know one row and want to find the first textarea in the next row:

```
$('#rowId').next().find('textarea').eq(0);
```

Comment: what if I am starting at rowId and need to find the next textarea (which is at rowId2). at that point I don't know rowId2

Comment: would it be faster to find all textareas on the page?

Comment: @gnomixa I don't know what you mean. You will need to be more clear about what "next" means.

Comment: @gnomixa Still not clear enough for me. It sound from your comments that you both want to start at a point but then perhaps keep finding the next, like the tab key. These are two different things.

Answer (score 4):

```
$textarea = $('#rowId textarea').eq(0);

$nextarea = $textarea.closest('tr').next().find('textarea').eq(0);
```

Just to clarify, $.fn.next() finds the next **sibling** in the DOM.

1. Starting from the textarea, first
   you have to find its parent-tr (
   $textarea.closest('tr') ).
2. From there, use next to find the next tr
   ( .next() )
3. Finally, find the first
   textarea within *that* tr (
   .find('textarea').eq(0) )

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#rowID textarea:first-child").val()
```